# Cannot setup HP All in one DJ3630

Tags: 14.04, printing

I have an ubuntu 14.04 on a asus laptop.
I followed the instructions in this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne

Here is the first command and its output (It is connected via usb cable, and i can choose that through the gui)

```
me@myasus:~$ sudo hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.14.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-13 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: No devices found on bus: usb
```

After running this command

```
 sudo hp-check -r
```

Here is what I get at the end:

```
--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

error: Unsupported model: DeskJet_3630_series

-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'libdbus-1-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'openssl' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libjpeg-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-bsd' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-client' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsane-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-1.0.0-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcupsimage2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsnmp-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'snmp-mibs-downloader' package is missing/incompatible 

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible 

Total Errors: 11
Total Warnings: 1

Run 'hp-doctor' command to prompt and fix the issues. 

Done.
```

I tried running hp-doctor as suggested in that page. Here is what it says:

```
me@myasus:~$ hp-doctor
error: Unable to open /home/me/.hplip/hp-doctor.lock lock file.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Ubuntu the needed drivers can be downloaded from HPLIP web site.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.15.11/hplip-3.15.11.run/download?use_mirror=ufpr

The downloaded files can be installed with sudo command:

```
sudo -i
sh hplip-3.15.11.run
hp-setup
```

The scanner can be used together with XSane, which can be installed by:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install xsane
hp-scan
```

After placing a sheet of paper on the scan unit and presses the scan button on the printer, a file `hpscan001.png` is created in the home directory.

Comment: I just tested the printer. After following the steps  you described it works like a charm now. I will try the scanner in the next days

Comment: the scanner does not work unfortunately. When I pressed the print button it generated a file with the name that you mentioned in the root folder. But it did not generate files anymore when I press now

Comment: just found a solution with simple scan. It just has better gui and works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have just succesfully set up an HP DJ3630  with Ubuntu 14.04.

To support DJ3630 I had to upgrade hplip 3.14.3 to the current level which is 3.15.6

There is excellent help on the  HP support site for Linux

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html